# Regular expression to extract string that meets specified criteria

Tags: .net, regex, string

I need to extract a substring from a line if substring meets the criteria below:

-starts with 3
-all characters are either numeric or dashes. If all numeric then from 10 characters in length up to 14, otherwise, if countains dashes, can be up to 19

I tried using

```
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(line.ToLower().Trim(), _
               "33[\d-]{10,19}", _
                  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

but the above m.Success returns false

Can anyone help to fix my regex expression?

Comment: Can you provide example data with success and failure conditions?

Comment: question, is `3----------` OK?

Comment: no, it has to have at least 10 digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  `^3(?:\d{9,13}|[\d-]{9,18})$`

Breakdown:

```
 ^                # BOS
 3                # Starts with '3'
 (?:              # Cluster
      \d{9,13}         # All digits, total 10 - 14
   |                 # or,
      [\d-]{9,18}      # Digits or dashes, total 10 - 19
 )                # End cluster
 $                # EOS
```

Comment: this matches `3----------` not sure if OK with OP

Comment: @alphabravo - why don't you ask him

Comment: this one didn't work for string "number: 3333333333"

Comment: @ElenaDBA - If its a substring, remove the anchors `3(?:\d{9,13}|[\d-]{9,18})`. I believe this was your statement `10 characters in length up to 14,`

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

```
^(?=(-?\d){10,14}$)3[0-9-]{9,18}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/160)

Comment: Please provide examples